# Using the apply function and selecting rows

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame presenting the number of trees at each plot (line) for each species (column).

I have 115 species of trees in columns and 6264 plots

> head(esp)

```
         02 03 04 05 06 07 08S 09 10 11 12P 12V 13B 13C 13G 14 15P 15S 16 17C
  600005  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0 16  0   0   0   0   0   0  0   0  32  0   0
  600008  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0   0   8   0   0   0  0   0   0  0   5
  600012  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  0   0   0  0   0
  600030  3  0  0  5  0  0   0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  0   0   0  0   0
  600033  0  0  0  0  0  0   0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  0   0   0  0   0
  600035  0  0  0  1  0  0   0  0  0  0   0   0   0   0   0  0   0   0  0   0
```

I'm trying to calculate the proportion of each species present at each plot.
I have tried to do this:

```
apply(esp,c(1,2), function(x){ifelse(x>0, x/sum(x)*100,0)})
```

What I would like to have is a data frame with the different plots as lines and the proportion of species present as column.

Thank you for your help.

I'm coming back just for a silly question: Now that I have my data frame with the proportion of each species at each plot, I want to select all the "pure" plots that have more than 80% of one species.

I know how to select the rows for one species:

```
pur<-prop[which(prop[,1]>80),]
```

This worked and gave me what I wanted but as I have 115 columns I have tried doing it with a loop:

```
for (i in 1:115){
prop[which(prop[,i]>80),]
}
```

But it didn't work out very well.

I have also tried with applied but which() isn't a function so it did not work either.

```
apply(prop,2,which(prop[,1]>80))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for ?

```
esp/rowSums(esp)

         X02 X03 X04   X05 X06 X07 X08S X09       X10 X11 X12P      X12V
600005 0.000   0   0 0.000   0   0    0   0 0.3333333   0    0 0.0000000
600008 0.000   0   0 0.000   0   0    0   0 0.0000000   0    0 0.6153846
600012   NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN       NaN NaN  NaN       NaN
600030 0.375   0   0 0.625   0   0    0   0 0.0000000   0    0 0.0000000
600033   NaN NaN NaN   NaN NaN NaN  NaN NaN       NaN NaN  NaN       NaN
600035 0.000   0   0 1.000   0   0    0   0 0.0000000   0    0 0.0000000
       X13B X13C X13G X14 X15P      X15S X16      X17C
600005    0    0    0   0    0 0.6666667   0 0.0000000
600008    0    0    0   0    0 0.0000000   0 0.3846154
600012  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN       NaN NaN       NaN
600030    0    0    0   0    0 0.0000000   0 0.0000000
600033  NaN  NaN  NaN NaN  NaN       NaN NaN       NaN
600035    0    0    0   0    0 0.0000000   0 0.0000000
```

The `NaN` (Not A Number) elements in the result are obviously due to the fact that some plots have a total number of species of 0, thus leading to a division by zero. You can replace these values with something else if you wish, this way for example :

```
res <- esp/rowSums(esp)
res <- sapply(res, function(v) {
  v[is.nan(v)] <- 0
  return(v)
})
round(res,2)

       X02 X03 X04  X05 X06 X07 X08S X09  X10 X11 X12P X12V X13B X13C X13G
[1,] 0.00   0   0 0.00   0   0    0   0 0.33   0    0 0.00    0    0    0
[2,] 0.00   0   0 0.00   0   0    0   0 0.00   0    0 0.62    0    0    0
[3,] 0.00   0   0 0.00   0   0    0   0 0.00   0    0 0.00    0    0    0
[4,] 0.38   0   0 0.62   0   0    0   0 0.00   0    0 0.00    0    0    0
[5,] 0.00   0   0 0.00   0   0    0   0 0.00   0    0 0.00    0    0    0
[6,] 0.00   0   0 1.00   0   0    0   0 0.00   0    0 0.00    0    0    0
     X14 X15P X15S X16 X17C
[1,]   0    0 0.67   0 0.00
[2,]   0    0 0.00   0 0.38
[3,]   0    0 0.00   0 0.00
[4,]   0    0 0.00   0 0.00
[5,]   0    0 0.00   0 0.00
[6,]   0    0 0.00   0 0.00
```

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for. It was a lot easier that what I thought. Thank you again Juba

Comment: I'm coming back just for a silly question: Now that I have my data frame with the proportion of each species at each plot, I ant to select all the "pure" plots that have more than 80% of one species.

Comment: @user2068053 Maybe you should ask it in another question.

Comment: I have actually edited my previous question. Is that the good way?

Comment: You can use something like `apply(prop, 1, function(v) any(v > 0.65))`

Comment: Thanks. I should be able to do something with this. i didn't know the any() function.

Comment: You're welcome. And I don't know about all the useful R functions I don't know about :)